# transform excel with python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, etl

I am using the bert model and conditions to clean the excel and in the excel they sometimes send me this value "-" with the hyphen and this column is of numerical type I already apply the strip property and it does not eliminate it and I don't know what to do so I have the code

```py
class LimpiezaNumericaBERT:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
        self.model = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')

    def obtener_embedding(self, texto):
        tokens = self.tokenizer(texto, return_tensors='pt')
        with torch.no_grad():
            outputs = self.model(**tokens)
        return np.mean(outputs.last_hidden_state.numpy(), axis=1)

    def limpiar_valor_numerico(self, valor):
        try:
            # Intenta convertir el valor a un número
            numero = float(valor)
            return numero
        except ValueError:
            # Si no se puede convertir, aplica el modelo de BERT para limpiar el valor
            return self.limpiar_con_bert(valor)

    def contiene_espacios_y_guiones_sin_numeros(self, texto):

       números
  
        return all(c == ' ' or c == '-' for c in texto if not c.isdigit() or c == '-')

    def limpiar_con_bert(self, texto):
        # Obtén la representación embebida del texto mediante BERT
        embedding = self.obtener_embedding(texto)

        # Verifica si el texto contiene espacios y guiones sin números
        if self.contiene_espacios_y_guiones_sin_numeros(texto):
            # Si es así, reemplaza por 0
            return 0
        else:
            return "valor a cambiar"

    def remover_tildes(self, texto):
        return ''.join((c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', texto) if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn'))

    def limpiar_valor_numerico_en_columna(self, columna):
        # Verifica si la columna contiene solo valores numéricos
        if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(columna):
            # Limpia y convierte a numérico todas las celdas de la columna
            columna = columna.apply(lambda x: self.limpiar_valor_numerico(x) if pd.notnull(x) else x)

            # Elimina espacios en blanco de izquierda
            columna = columna.apply(lambda x: str(x).lstrip() if pd.notnull(x) else x)

        else:
            # Si la columna no es de tipo numérico, deja los valores como están
            columna = columna.apply(lambda x: x if pd.notnull(x) else x)

        return columna

y este lo llamo de este metodo 

def edit_all_numeric_columns(self, file_path):
        df_dict = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None)

        hojas_a_analizar = ["FORM 2 GASTO AO&M-C SPEE",
                            "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE",
                            "FORM 4 RA SPEE",
                            "FORM 5 SIGDE SPEE",
                            "FORM 6 EXPANSION SPEE",
                            "FORM 7 DISPON_CONFIAB SPEE",
                            "FORM 8 O-PROGRAMAS SPEE",
                            "FORM 9 O-RECURSOS SPEE",
                            "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M SAPG",
                            "FORM 3 CALIDAD SAPG",
                            "FORM 4 EXPANSION SAPG",
                            "FORM 5 O-PROGRAMAS SAPG",
                            "FORM 6 O-RECURSOS SAPG"]

        excepciones = {
            "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE": ["distribuidoras",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "codigo_ecostos",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edds",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones"],
            "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M-C SPEE": ["distribuidoras",
                                    "arrastre_nro_partida",
                                    "descripcion_partida",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "tipo_gasto",
                                    "grupo_gasto"],
            "FORM 4 RA SPEE": [     "distribuidora",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "codigo_ecostos",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones" ],
            "FORM 5 SIGDE SPEE":[   "distribuidora",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones"  ],
            "FORM 6 EXPANSION SPEE":["distribuidora",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones"  ],          
            "FORM 7 DISPON_CONFIAB SPEE":["descripcion",
                                    "etapa_funcional"],
            "FORM 8 O-PROGRAMAS SPEE":["otros_programas_proy",
                                    "programa",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "observaciones"],
            "FORM 9 O-RECURSOS SPEE": ["otros_recursos_proy",
                                    "programa",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "observaciones"],
            "FORM 2 GASTO AO&M SAPG": ["distribuidora",
                                    "arrastre_nro_partida",
                                    "descripcion_partida",
                                    "etapa_funcional",
                                    "tipo_gasto",
                                    "grupo_gasto"],
            "FORM 3 CALIDAD SPEE": ["distribuidora",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "proyecto_calif_ecostos",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "codigo_ecostos",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones"],
            "FORM 4 EXPANSION SAPG": ["distribuidora",
                                    "proyecto_arraste",
                                    "proyecto_calif_eco",
                                    "ano_calificacion",
                                    "codigo_ecostos",
                                    "cod_proyecto_edd",
                                    "nombre_proyecto",
                                    "objeto_proyecto",
                                    "provincia",
                                    "canton",
                                    "parroquia",
                                    "estado_proyecto",
                                    "ejec_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_inicio_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_pro_fin_proyecto",
                                    "fecha_fin_proyecto",
                                    "observaciones"  ],
            "FORM 5 O-PROGRAMAS SAPG":["otros_programas_proy",
                                    "programa",
                                    "observaciones"],
            "FORM 6 O-RECURSOS SAPG": ["otros_recursos_proy",
                                    "programa",
                                    "observaciones"]   
        }

        for hoja in hojas_a_analizar:
            try:
                if hoja in df_dict:
                    # Obtiene las columnas numéricas
                    columnas_numericas = df_dict[hoja].select_dtypes(include=[np.number]).columns

                    # Excluye las columnas especificadas en las excepciones
                    if hoja in excepciones and excepciones[hoja]:
                        columnas_numericas = [col for col in columnas_numericas if col not in excepciones[hoja]]

                    # Limpia y convierte a numérico todas las columnas identificadas
                    for columna in columnas_numericas:
                        df_dict[hoja][columna] = self.limpieza_numerica_bert.limpiar_valor_numerico_en_columna(df_dict[hoja][columna])

                    print(f"Columnas numéricas en la hoja {hoja} procesadas con éxito.")
            except KeyError:
                print(f"La hoja '{hoja}' no está presente en el archivo de Excel.")

        # Obtén el nombre del archivo sin la extensión
        file_name_no_extension = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file_path))[0]

        # Construir el nombre del archivo final con el prefijo "modificado_"
        output_file_name = f"modificado_{file_name_no_extension}.xlsx"
        
        # Construir la ruta completa del archivo final
        output_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_folder, output_file_name)

        # Guardar el archivo final
        with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
            for hoja, df_hoja in df_dict.items():
                df_hoja.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=hoja, index=False)

        return output_file_path
```

and implemented bert and strip to remove the spaces but it does not remove them. I attached a photo of the excel and these libraries
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd
import os
import unicodedata
from datetime import datetime
from shutil import move
import torch
import numpy as np
from Levenshtein import distance
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import re

[image]

Comment: I don't see `-` in your `Excel`. Maybe this `-` doesn't exist but `Excel` automatically display it when there is some problem with data - and this means you can't remove it in data but you would have to change configuration directly in `Excel` to remove it from screen.

Comment: maybe there is no spaces in data but only `Excel` display it - and it needs to change configuration in `Excel` (ie. check if all cells has the same formatting, or change `alignement` to `right`)

Comment: maybe write data in CSV and open in any text editor to see if you really have `-` and spaces in data. As for me problem is not data in file but only `Excel` which reformat data when it display it.

Comment: you may also use `print()` in code to see what you really have in data. If you have data without `-` and without spaces then it can confirm that all problem is how `Excel` displays data on screen.